# How to use call fine uploader with java applete

Tags: fine-uploader

I'm using fine uploader manual upload to upload files from java applete. File uploaded is being called but it generates an error messages of no file selected. How to link files with fine uploader.

```
      // My applet for browse button.   
        <applet id="FileApplet" code = "net.codejava.applet.FileBrowseApplet.class"
                archive="FileApplet.jar"
                width="250"
                name="FileApplet"
                            height="50">
        </applet>
//function to call fine uplader when files are selected 
    function showDetailHandler(json) {
     var manualuploaderVideo = getVideoUploader();   
     manualuploaderVideo.fineUploader('uploadStoredFiles');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this isn't possible.  Fine Uploader handles `<input type="file">` elements, `Blob`, or `File` objects.  Your java applet won't be able to send it any of those.